# Javascript search for word in text and change another td

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

Here is my XSL code for the table in question:

```
<table id="dataTable" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: left;">Action</th>
            <th>Element</th>
            <th>Parameter</th>
            <th>Pass/Fail</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <xsl:for-each select="trace/step">
            <tr>
                <td id = "actionc" style="text-align: left;">
                 <xsl:value-of select="action"/></td>
                 <td id="elementc"><xsl:value-of select="element"/></td>
                 <td id="paramc"><xsl:value-of select="parameter"/></td>
                 <td id="passfailc"></td>
             </tr>
         </xsl:for-each>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('actionc');
var word = 'error:';
var textValue=textarea.value;
if (textValue.indexOf(word) != -1) {
    $('#passfailc').append('X');
}
else {
    $('#passfailc').append('O');
}
```

Example XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="output.xsl"?>
<testResults>
<testResult endTime="1409040996817" id="Test 1(hello)" result="PASS" startTime="1409040974962">
    <trace>
        <step id="1" timestamp="1409040983154">
            <action>page action: click</action>
            <element>Home Page: Search Button</element>
            <parameter/>
        </step>
        <step id="2" timestamp="1409040983594">
            <action>page action: set text</action>
            <element>Home Page: Search Input Text</element>
            <parameter>bike</parameter>
        </step>
        <step id="3" timestamp="1409040987677">
            <action>page action: click</action>
            <element>Results Page: Top Item</element>
            <parameter/>
        </step>
        <step id="4" timestamp="1409040995052">
            <action>page action: Get an attributes value from an element</action>
            <element>Item Page: Price Text</element>
            <parameter/>
        </step>
    </trace>
</testResult>

<testResult endTime="1409040827762" id="Test 2(com.thetestpeople.ebaydemo.mobileweb.test.SearchItemTest)" result="ERROR" startTime="1409040786110"><trace><step id="1" timestamp="1409040792321"><action>page action: navigate to</action><element/><parameter>http://www.buystuff.com/</parameter></step><step id="2" timestamp="1409040794466"><action>page action: set text</action><element>Home Page: Search Input Text</element><parameter>bike</parameter></step><step id="3" timestamp="1409040827687">
<action>error: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'Apeldoorn.local', ip: '10.0.1.7', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.4', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'Apeldoorn.local', ip: '10.0.1.7', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.4', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
</action>
<element/><parameter/></step></trace></testResult>
</testResults>
```

When I open the XML file, everything works but it isn't putting anything in the Pass/Fail column? I am very new to Javascript and XML so please go easy on me!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't told it to put anything in the Pass/Fail column. What do **want** to put there?

Comment: Oh.. I want to put an "X" in if the word "error" is in the "Action" column and "O" if it isn't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to put an "X" in if the word "error" is in the "Action" column
>   and "O" if it isn't there.

Try:

```
<td id="passfailc">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(action, 'error')">X</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>O</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</td>
```

Comment: Argh and I've been messing about with JS for ages! Thank you very much!

Comment: @lordhazra Note that this is a somewhat pedestrian solution; for example, it will return positive if action contains "terror". I now see that in your JS attempt you used "error:". Perhaps a better test would look for `starts-with(action, 'error:')`?

Comment: Ah ok, I will update with the "starts-with" option. Many thanks once again.